# Most efficient way to play Nasus?

Tags: league-of-legends

When I play Nasus (Solo top of course) there's always disputes on what I should be doing.
I run Teleport + Flash to ensue map control and for an escape.

However I have 2 questions,

How do you correctly lane with Nasus? (Pushing, Freezing, Last hitting with Q, Using Q for harass?)

and also, how do you deal with people that don't understand that Nasus is relatively weak until he farms up? (I've witnessed a lot of people initiate 4v5s constantly without thinking then proceed to blame it on me)

Comment: I prefer to run teleport and ghost since one of Nasus' main weaknesses is how easily he can be kited.

Comment: @Rapida, really? He has one of the best slows in the game.

Comment: @Jay Most guides point out kiting is one of his kits major weaknesses. If you have a slow you can completely negate his ultimate, and if he can't reach you to Q then he has almost no damage. His wither is good, but it only effects a single target (ideally the AD). This doesn't really help if you wither then get CC'ed for the duration of the wither. Ghost allows you to react if you misuse your wither for whatever reason or get CC'ed during it. It also makes for a much scarier initiation if you are the tankiest character on your team.

Answer (score 3):

During laning phase, just last hit with your Q and harass with it if the enemy gets bold. A good combo is to Wither > Siphoning Strike > and while Wither is nearing its peak slow put a Circle down on them and back off. Be sure to focus as much as you can on last hitting with Q but don't die. Remember that Nasus has built in lifesteal, so his Q can be really good for getting his health back up in a pinch.

In teamfights just Wither the AD Carry that does the most damage and Q the squishiest thing within reach while trying to land the Circle on as many enemies as possible.

As for dealing with people who don't understand certain champions, just try to explain your playstyle or your Champion's role during Champion select and remind forgetful types during the match when you can.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you pick Nasus and have solo top, you have one duty and only one purpose for the first 20 minutes of the game.  That would be farm your Q (Siphoning Strike).  Hopefully your team realizes this, as that is pretty much all you do on Nasus to make him most effective.  You trade a weak early game for an amazing late game one-shot killing machine as well as the ability to do baron easily by level 11.  Unless you are in the one of 4 favorable matchups Nasus has, you generally will let the lane push and farm your Q at tower.  If you can't farm your Q at tower, then you need more practice with Nasus.